# Globally handle WPF exceptions without a WPF Application object

Tags: c#, wpf, vba, exception, interop

WPF provides a very convenient way to handle unexpected exceptions: I can just attach a handler to the [Application.DispatcherUnhandledException event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx) and all unhandled exceptions go this way:

```
Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += (sender, e) => {
    // Show message, log exception, etc.
};
```

This works great for *WPF application projects*. Now, I have a **library with WPF windows**, which is called from a **non-WPF application** (it's a legacy VBA app, and the WPF library is made accessible via COM interop).

So, the thing is: I can create, open and show WPF windows (this works fine), but *I don't have an `Application` instance*. `Application.Current` is `null`. I use the WPF classes, but I operate them outside the WPF application framework.

Currently, the only drawback of this solution is that exceptions in WPF window event handler code are silently swallowed:

```
void Button_click(sender as object, e as RoutedEventArgs) {
    ...
    // some exception occurs here, but nobody hears her scream
    ...
}
```

I don't like that. I'd like to log them and show error messages.

**My question**: Is there a way to globally catch unhandled exceptions in this scenario or do I have to add a gerneric try-catch-log block to every WPF window event handler code I write?

What I have tried:

- Attaching to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`. Doesn't work. Exceptions don't get there.
- Reading the relevant parts of MSDN regarding WPF and Win32 interop ([Ref 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742474.aspx), [Ref 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522.aspx), [Ref 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744829.aspx)). Exceptions are not mentioned there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach to the `Dispatcher` instead:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.DispatcherUnhandledException += (sender, e) => { 
    // Show message, log exception, etc. 
};
```

If no dispatcher exists yet, accessing `CurrentDispatcher` automatically creates a singleton Dispatcher which will also be used by the WPF windows.